# Manifest not being well-formed

Tags: android

Can someone please see what's wrogn with my Manifest.xml. Eclipse keeps on saying that "The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.", but I couldn't find which part is wrong.

TIA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.testapp.pricechecker" 
android:versionCode="1" 
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_price_checker"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".VideoPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".GetProductInformationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_get_product_information"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppSettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_app_settings"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you close manifest? The root node of a manifest is the manifest tag, and that is not closed in the XML you gave.

Comment: Try opening the xml in a browser. It should help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: I did that and also checked it via online XML parser and no problems were found. I tried the CLEAN option and it seemed to fix the problem but my R file went missing. I then deleted the .android folder and everything worked.

Comment: then post it as an answer and accept it..

Answer (score 0):

you need to close the node at the end...

```
</manifest>
```